# Cannot use a layout from another class in a different file

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

In my litttle app I'm trying to put views into the tabs of this activity.  What I first try to do is set up the views, with some of the code found in other classes (which are in other files).  Here's the class which builds the tabs and sets up the code.

CreateCharacterTabsActivity.java

```
package com.androidGuy.DnDApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

public class CreateCharacterTabsActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener  {
private TabHost tabHost;
private TableLayout scoreTable;
private LinearLayout raceLayout;

private CharacterAbilityScoresActivity abilityScoresActivity;

// Tab tags: got to love them.
private static final String ABILITY_SCORES_TAB = "scores";
private static final String RACE_TAB = "race";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_layout);

    // Set up them tabs.
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    // Set up the tabhost.
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    scoreTable = (TableLayout) abilityScoresActivity.getAbilityScoreTable();
    raceLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.raceLayout);



    // Add views to the tab host.
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(ABILITY_SCORES_TAB).setIndicator("Scores").setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
            return scoreTable;
        }
    }));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(RACE_TAB).setIndicator("Races").setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String arg1) {
            return raceLayout;
        }
    }));

    // I have heard this is a hack brought upon by a bug.
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}


public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

It gets other code from this class.

CharacterAbilityScoresActivity.java

```
package com.androidGuy.DnDApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

/* This is for character class scores, settings, and... Stuff. */
import com.androidGuy.DnDApp.CharacterData;

public class CharacterAbilityScoresActivity extends Activity {

CharacterData characterData = new CharacterData();

private Spinner strengthSpinner;
private Spinner dexteritySpinner;
private Spinner constitutionSpinner;
private Spinner intelligenceSpinner;
private Spinner wisdomSpinner;
private Spinner charismaSpinner;
private ArrayAdapter<?> adapter;
private TableLayout abilityScoreTable;

public TableLayout getAbilityScoreTable() {
    return abilityScoreTable;
}

/* Le constructor.  Set up all of the fields (the adapters and the spinner boxes) and return
 * a tabletLayout objects (or at least, I hope that's how it'll work). */
CharacterAbilityScoresActivity() {

    final LayoutInflater Die_Fledermaus = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    abilityScoreTable = (TableLayout) Die_Fledermaus.inflate(R.layout.ability_score_spinners, null);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Die_Fledermaus.getContext(), R.array.string_ability_scores, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    /* The ability score spinners */
    strengthSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.StrengthSpinner);

    strengthSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    strengthSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                    characterData.setStrengthScore(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ability_scores)[(int) strengthSpinner.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2)]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });

    dexteritySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dexteritySpinner);

    dexteritySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    dexteritySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                        characterData.setDexterityScore(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ability_scores)[(int) dexteritySpinner.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2)]);

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }

            });

    constitutionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ConstitutionSpinner);
    constitutionSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    constitutionSpinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int pos, long id) {
                    characterData.setConstitutionScore(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ability_scores)[(int) constitutionSpinner.getItemIdAtPosition(pos)]);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });

    intelligenceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.intelligenceSpinner);
    intelligenceSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    intelligenceSpinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int pos, long id) {
                    characterData.setIntelligenceScore(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ability_scores)[(int) intelligenceSpinner.getItemIdAtPosition(pos)]);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });

    wisdomSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.WisdomSpinner);
    wisdomSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    wisdomSpinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    characterData.setWisdomScore(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ability_scores)[(int) wisdomSpinner.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2)]);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }

            });

    charismaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.CharismaSpinner);
    charismaSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    charismaSpinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    characterData.setCharismaScore(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ability_scores)[(int) charismaSpinner.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2)]);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }

            });
    }   
}
```

What is suppose to happen is the constructor in `CharacterAbilityScoresActivity` creates all of the spin boxes and assigns them adapters.  I then try to return the tableLayout which holds them in the `createTabContent()` method in `CreateCharacterTabsActivity`.  What happens, though, is that an error occurs around `tabHost.setup()` (that's where the stack trace says the error is occuring).

[edit] Just to help further, here's the stack trace.

```
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidGuy.DnDApp/com.androidGuy.DnDApp.CreateCharacterTabsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at com.androidGuy.DnDApp.CreateCharacterTabsActivity.onCreate(CreateCharacterTabsActivity.java:34)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-16 13:40:47.100: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(386):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I assume the lost backtick in your first code block was by mistake; I removed it so the formatting comes trough better ;). Further more: you should try and remove some of the code (everything that has got nothign to do with the error) so you have a minimal example, and you should actually paste the error (stacktrace).

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no stacktrace and an \infty amount of code, this looks shakey:

```
setContentView(R.layout.simple_layout);

// Set up them tabs.
tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

You'v got to realise that `findViewById` does NOT find a random view in any XML, but finds view on your screen.

As the view with id `tabhost` is in tabs.xml, and as far as I can see you only have `simple_layout` on screen, at this point the variable `tabHost` will be `null`.

So this next line:

```
tabHost.setup();
```

Will give you a `nullpointerexception`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nanne.  So I should set a layout with more views to it?  Or just change up the tabs.xml file?

Comment: You can, but dont have to. The only thing you cant do is use 'findviewbyid' on views (ids) that are not on the screen. You can add them to the xml you are viewing if that is what you need, but you can also use an inflater to read an xml an use 'addview'.

Comment: Ah, okay.  So I'll inflate the layouts and try to use "addview".